# How to load locales in Angular 5

Tags: angular, internationalization

I use NgLocaleLocalization, which is part of the i18n code in Angular. Moving from Angular 4 to 5 I now need to do something like this, as detailed in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes):

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

// the second parameter 'fr' is optional
registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr');
```

Which is great for one language. I have loads more (around 50).

Is this a sensible way to do it?:

```
import locale_ar from "@angular/common/locales/ar";
import locale_bg from "@angular/common/locales/bg";
import locale_cs from "@angular/common/locales/cs";
import locale_da from "@angular/common/locales/da";
// around 45 more import statements
import locale_sv from "@angular/common/locales/sv";


const locales: [string, (string | number | string[] | string[][] | number[] | ((n: number) => number))[]][] = [
    ["ar", locale_ar], ["bg", locale_bg], ["cs", locale_cs], ["da", locale_da],
    // around 45 more items here
    ["sv-SE", locale_sv]
];

(() => {
    for (const locale of locales) {
        registerLocaleData(locale[1], locale[0]);
    }
})();
```

This, in my opinion, looks a little crazy. **But is it the right thing to do?**

Also, **is there any reason I should defer calling registerLocaleData until I know I need it or is it okay registering them here all at once?**

If I do defer registering, do I need to keep track so I don't double register?

Comment: I'm also stuck here only, I have to load all the locales and then as per user's language preference set on browser, I will assign the value to LOCALE_ID. But didn't find anything yet to load all the locales and bundle it. Have you find a solution about it?

Comment: @HemendraSinghChauhan The code above works, use that if you want. But it does mean registering all possible locals all the time

Comment: So no one ever responded?  There's got to be a better way.... :-/

Comment: Valid question! Surprised that it has no answers so far!